# is there a way to keep the shrinked windows of the same program in the same order?

Tags: window

I will make an example: if I open 2 or more files with text editor and I work in both of them, when I click on the text editor at the bottom bar to choose which file to use, the last one I used will always be at the far left of the previews. 
This annoys me very much, I would like that the first file I open keeps the first place, the second one keeps the second place, and so on, from left to right. Is there a way to do this?

This happens with every program obviously, also with terminal for example; i would like to change it for all

Comment: Hello wattbatt, Welcome to askubuntu community. Can you please mention the version of Ubuntu you are using? I have seen this behavior only on versions above 16.04. As a temporary work around and if you are interested in keyboard shortcuts, you can use "alt + `" (press and hold "alt" key and press block quote key, do not confuse the key with single quote key, '. ` key is different than ' key.). Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: my version is 18.04; I don't understand what is your shortcut is supposed to do, if I i understood it. I kept pressed alt and then "

Comment: No its alt + `  ` key is placed left side of number "1" key.